# Error when using Scipy's differential_evolution function

Tags: python, scipy, differential-evolution

I'm trying to do parameterization work for a college activity, but I've been encountering problems with Scipy's differential_evolution function (which is what our professor instructed us to use). I'm following the same steps that the teacher did in class, but I'm receiving the following error message: "RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'"

Following is my code (I'm using jupyter, but I joined the two cells to make it easier to show here):

```
x = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
y = [0.0, 1.8, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 3.6, 3.4, 2.8, 0.0]

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize=3, label='Dados')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

def model_reta(x, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 ):
  return c0+c1*x+c2*pow(x,2)+c3*pow(x,3)+c4*pow(x,4)+c5*pow(x,5)

def model(params):
  sol = model_reta(x, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5])

  erro = np.linalg.norm(y-sol, 1)/np.linalg.norm(y, 1)

  return [erro, sol, x]

def model_adj(x, args):
  result = model(x)
  return result[0]

bounds = [(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),]

result = differential_evolution(model_adj, bounds, strategy='best1bin', disp=True)
```

Full error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentialevolution.py:1146, in DifferentialEvolutionSolver._calculate_population_energies(self, population)
   1145 try:
-> 1146     calc_energies = list(
   1147         self._mapwrapper(self.func, parameters_pop[0:S])
   1148     )
   1149     calc_energies = np.squeeze(calc_energies)

File c:\Users\filip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py:360, in _FunctionWrapper.__call__(self, x)
    359 def __call__(self, x):
--> 360     return self.f(x, *self.args)

TypeError: model_adj() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Scripts Python\atividade_integracao_numerica\integracao_numerica.ipynb Cell 9 line 1
     13   return result[0]
     15 bounds = [(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),(-10, 10),]
---> 17 result = differential_evolution(model_adj, bounds, strategy='best1bin', disp=True)
     18 '''
     19 print(result.x)
     20 erro, sol, x = model(result.x)
...
   1156     ) from e
   1158 if calc_energies.size != S:
   1159     if self.vectorized:

RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'
```

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You seem of have left out specifying `args=()` inside your call to `differential_evolution()` yet you have `args` listed in your `model_adj()` function.  Note as spelled out [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) `args` is to be a tuple. There's options though. In your case, at present you don't use any of the `args` in your `model_adj()` function and so the first, and easiest option I think is to just leave out `args` in your function, like `def model_adj(x):`. Alternatively, you could specify a default ...

Comment: <continued> parameter for args like `def model_adj(x, args = (1,1)):` and then your call may work **as it is now**. Or, a third option would be to pass a dummy `args` tuple in that won't get used and leave your function as is.  Examples of passing in `args` when you call `differential_evolution()` are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68017570/8508004).

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but neither worked :(
What I'm finding most strange is that in the reference work that my professor gave us, there are no `args`, and yet it works. But what I'm doing now, no!

Comment: I found out how to solve it, I just had to transform my `x` and `y` into numpy arrays

Comment: "the reference work that my professor gave us, there are no `args`"? But where? In the call or in the defining of the `model_adj()` function. Glad you find a way to get it to work. Did it work exactly with the code you posted otherwise? Either way, it is common to post an 'UPDATE' at the end of your own post with the solution you found that works.